# Re-accessing input text data through JS from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a server which I am storing standard text inputs once a submit button has been clicked, I have done this successfully and now need to recall all the inputs on a different button click. My lack of understanding of PHP starts to kick me as I have little to no idea how to retrieve this, I know that data within PHP files once ran is deleted so I need to create some sort of "storage" ( I found the use of $_SESSION to be the go to thing for this).

I then need to use my JS file to somehow recall the data that is temporarily stored but again have no idea how I can get an array that is stored on a PHP file across to a JS file.

Any brief explanation oh how this is done would be greatly appreciated as I am extremely new to PHP!

For reference I currently have:

JS:

```
function writeDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "gethint.php";
  var input = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var clicker = document.getElementById("submit");

  xhttp.open("POST", "gethint.php", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form- 
  urlencoded");

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        alert("Form Was Submitted");
    // var returnData = xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
   xhttp.send("input= " + input);
} 

  function readDoc() {
  var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
  xxhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        alert("Data retrieved")
       // var returnData = xhttp.responseText;
    }
}
  xxhttp.open("GET", "gethint.php", true);
  xxhttp.send();
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <label>Text Input To Save: </label>
    <br></br>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="20" id="text" name="textInput"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="writeDoc()">
    <br></br>
    <label>Retrieve Text :</label> <input type="button" id="getText" 
    onclick="readDoc()">
</body>
```

PHP:

```
<?
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["input_data"] = $_POST;
print_r($_POST);
echo "Text Submitted". $_POST["input"];
print_r($_REQUEST);
echo "Text Retrieved" . $_REQUEST["input"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php you can encode the post data as json like so:

```
$_SESSION['input_data'] = json_encode($_POST);
```

And in your js you can the get the data by decoding it like so:

```
var data = JSON.parse('<?php echo $_SESSION["input_data"]; ?>');
```

This will give you a js object that you can access using the name you gave your input tags in your html.

ex: data.textInput would get that value of the textarea.

Comment: On a side note, isn't it wrong to use php code within a JS file? instead I wrote     this.responseText    .

Comment: I think this should answer your question. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript

Answer (score 0):

To easily access the php data in js , you can store the data in session.also use json format to throw data to js and access it in js via jeson array key value format if you have multiple form field to store and access.
Use json_encode() to throw from php to js. 
Also you can save this data in cookie. Session and cookie are temporary way to store data. For permanent storage use a database like mysql and call this from js with json.